# How to use stuff function in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I asked the stuff function in Oralce question several months ago and would like to revisit this question. The problem was when using the WM_CONCAT function (in Oracle), the result included the (,) in the front or before the field I wanted to stuff.

I googled to find a solution for this but had no success so far. What should I need to include in the WM_CONCAT function in order to remove the extra empty string for the field I'd like to stuff?

I have some sample records below

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
  COMPANY VARCHAR (50),
  ID INT,
  PRODUCT VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('APPLES', '123', 'IPHONE4')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('APPLES', '123', 'IPHONE4S')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('APPLES', '123', 'IPHONE5')


INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('SAMSUNG', '124', 'GALAXY S2')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('SAMSUNG', '124', 'GALAXY S3')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('SAMSUNG', '124', 'GALAXY S4')


INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('NOKIA', '125', 'C5-02')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('NOKIA', '125', 'C5-03')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('NOKIA', '125', 'C5-04')
```

When running this query it produces as

```
SELECT
COMPANY,
ID,
WM_CONCAT(PRODUCT) AS PRODUCT, --STUFF PRODUCT COLUMN
FROM
(
   SELECT
   COMPANY,
   ID,
   PRODUCT
   FROM #TEMP
 )
GROUP BY COMPANY, ID


COMPANY     ID      PRODUCT
APPLES      123     IPHONE4, IPHONE4S, IPHONE5
SAMSUNG     124     ,GALAXY S2, GALAXY S3, GALAXY S4
NOKIA       125     ,C5-02, C5-03, C5-04
```

Comment: Please double check which RDBMS you are using. You stated in a comment to polppan's answer that you used `#` in your table definition to create a temporary table. That is Microsoft SQL Server syntax, possible others. On Oracle the result is `ORA-00911: invalid character`.

Comment: @Shanon Serverance - I was wrong. You were right! It was MS SQL syntax. I overlooked it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the:

```
WM_CONCAT(PRODUCT)
```

with:

```
LTRIM(WM_CONCAT(PRODUCT),',')
```

This will remove any leading commas from your column.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following query

```
SELECT
COMPANY,
ID,
WM_CONCAT(PRODUCT) AS PRODUCT
FROM
(
   SELECT
   COMPANY,
   ID,
   PRODUCT
   FROM TEMP
 )
GROUP BY COMPANY, ID
```

Is this the output you are looking for?

```
NOKIA   125 C5-02,C5-04,C5-03
APPLES  123 IPHONE4,IPHONE5,IPHONE4S
SAMSUNG 124 GALAXY S2,GALAXY S4,GALAXY S3
```

Query can be this way as well

```
SELECT
COMPANY,
ID,
WM_CONCAT(PRODUCT) AS PRODUCT
FROM TEMP
--(
--   SELECT
--   COMPANY,
--   ID,
--   PRODUCT
--   FROM TEMP
-- )
GROUP BY COMPANY, ID
```

Comment: that's what i have in the query. Not sure what you had the query posted. Please let me know the difference

Comment: @joe is this required? `, --STUFF PRODUCT COLUMN` with that comma you may not be able to run the query I guess.

Comment: Thanks, Polppan. I remove the comma but the result still show the (,). Ah

Comment: @joe I have updated my answer, I have included the results. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @joe Another point is remove `#` sign from your table definition, insert and select statements. Any particular reason for using `#` sign?

Comment: I do not have full access to create a table. So i had to create a temporary table which requires the # sign to demonstrate my point.

Comment: So are you able to get the desired output?

Comment: sorry. I did not get the desired output. I had this tested bofore as well. Just not sure how to remove the comma (,) in the front. Ah, Ah, Ah

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19654/discussion-between-polppan-and-joe)

Comment: @joe what is your database version?

Comment: Sorry, Internet was down. I use Oracle 8i

Comment: @joe Sorry I do not have 8i to test, I guess that might one of the reason you are getting not the correct output

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle PL/SQL, at least in the version 19c that I'm using, there is a LISTAGG() function that is the equivalent of Stuff().  There is no WM_CONCAT in that implementation.