# duplicate results

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

Good day! I am running an extract of our Rolodex and including some user-defined fields, as you can below:

The problem I have is that I am getting duplicate results when a Rolodex entry qualifies for more than one case. So if a company is a 'Bell Owner or Operator' and a 'Fixed Wing' the result includes one entry for each, duplicating the email address.

Thank you for the help, this must be basic for y'all.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 24
                THEN
                    'Bell Owner or Operator'
    END AS "Bell Owner or Operator",
        CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 26
                THEN
                    'Fixed Wing'
    END AS "Fixed Wing",
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 25
                THEN
                    'Rotorcraft'
    END AS "Rotorcraft",
    rdx.RDX_CONTACT_NAME, rdx.TITLE, rdx.PHONE_NUMBER, rdx.MOBILE_PHONE, rdx.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
    cmp.COMPANY_NAME, cmp.COMPANY_CODE, cmp.ATTENTION, cmp.ADDRESS1, cmp.ADDRESS2, cmp.ADDRESS3, cmp.CITY, cmp.COUNTRY, cmp.STATE, cmp.ZIP_CODE, cmp.PHONE_NUMBER, cmp.EMAIL_ADDRESS, cmp.NOTES, cmp.VENDOR_FLAG, cmp.CUSTOMER_FLAG,
    act.TAIL_NUMBER, act.SERIAL, mdl.MODEL_NUMBER, mdl.DESCRIPTION
FROM ROLODEX rdx
JOIN COMPANY_ROLODEX cprol ON cprol.RDX_AUTO_KEY = rdx.RDX_AUTO_KEY
JOIN COMPANIES cmp ON cprol.CMP_AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN UDA_CHECKED uda ON uda.AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN USER_DEFINED_ATTRIBUTES attr ON uda.UDA_AUTO_KEY = attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN AIRCRAFT act ON act.CMP_OWNER = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN MODEL mdl ON mdl.MDL_AUTO_KEY = act.MDL_AUTO_KEY
WHERE attr.AUTO_KEY_PREFIX = 'CMP'
AND
rdx.HISTORICAL = 'F'
```

Comment: In your joins, LINK cmp to cprol, uda to cmp, and act to uda. So, cmp depends on cprol, and uda on cmp, and act on uda. One-to-One dependency

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting duplicated rows, then one of your joins are finding multiple matches. Additionally, your case statement looks incorrect (possibly). Normally should be one instead of three.

```
CASE
    WHEN
        attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 24
            THEN
                'Bell Owner or Operator'
    WHEN
        attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 26
            THEN
                'Fixed Wing'
    WHEN
        attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 25
            THEN
                'Rotorcraft'
END AS [ColumnNameForThis],
```

Comment: I a doing 3 and not one because one company may be all three things, so I need a column for each. am I doing that right?

Comment: @Stephen you are not doing it right, because your 3 cases will only ever satisfy one out of three criteria since it using same column `attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY` hence why one case I've proposed merges them into single column.

Comment: you are right about a duplicate row. the cmp.auto key comes up multiple times in the uda_checked table, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to combine the results into one row.

Comment: @Stephen So correct me if I am wrong, you have multiples coming out of the join with `COMPANIES` table which in turns gives you multiple `attr.UDA_AUTO_KEYS` and you want these to be stuffed into one column. In this case you will need to use `WM_CONCAT` function. Take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421902/how-to-use-stuff-function-in-oracle perhaps its similar to what your problem is on this one.